# Как исправить ошибку Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyModule::unsetAttributes()

Tags: php, yii

При выполнении `$model->unsetAttributes()` получаю ошибку

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyModule::unsetAttributes()

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Это ответ на какой вопрос?

Comment: автор, видимо, просто хотел поделиться полезным наблюдением:)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это вообще не вопрос.

Comment: Это все конечно здорово, но без описания класса `MyModule` сказать хоть что-то конкретное невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что у вас в переменной не модель, а экземпляр класса `MyModule` у которого нету метода `unsetAttributes()`.

Исправить нужно во-первых создание модели, а во вторых нужно добавить проверку, что бы не пугать обычных юзеров:

```
if(method_exists($model, 'unsetAttributes')){
    // action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ из самого вопроса.

---

Скорее всего, модель с таким же названием уже где-то инициализированна. Т.к. чаще всего инициализируют модели и компоненты так:

```
$this->setImport(array(
    'mymodules.models.*',
));
```

то возможно автоматом где зацепили.